# How to extract longitude and langitude from keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following setup for my data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        data={'place_id': ['AXRT'],
              'geometry': [{'location': {'lat': 51.112278, 'lng': 20.747889},
                            'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 51.11367217989272,
                                                       'lng': 20.74911952989272},
                                         'southwest': {'lat': 51.11097252010727,
                                                       'lng': 20.74641987010727}}}]})
```

Now I am trying to arrive at having `place_id`, `lat` and `lng` in columns.

My code is:

```
out = df[['place_id']].join(df['geometry'].apply(pd.Series)['location'].apply(pd.Series))
```

But unfortunately nothing is happening. I have still my core column including the entire `"geometry"`.

Comment: I've tried you code above and it worked. Please see the output: https://ibb.co/nPt26H6

Comment: Thanx Jay. Unfortunately, from some reason it does not work for my bigger data frame under the below link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qS8oX2IjlElHgqLjINUslRCtlpQ8PySi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105719268781273090568&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I really do not get it, though tried from different angles -:)

Comment: I am getting an error: KeyError: 'location'

Comment: I see. Please see my anwer.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike creating dataframe with `pd.DataFrame()`, when you read the data from the file, `df['geometry']` contains string representation of `dict`.

e.g.

> "{'location': {'lat': 51.112278, 'lng': 20.747889}, 'viewport':
> {'northeast': {'lat': 51.11367217989272, 'lng': 20.74911952989272},
> 'southwest': {'lat': 51.11097252010727, 'lng': 20.74641987010727}}}"

So, you need to convert it to `dict` using `ast.literal_eval()`.

```
import ast

df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x : ast.literal_eval(x))
out = df[['place_id']].join(df['geometry'].apply(pd.Series)['location'].apply(pd.Series))
```

Output:

> ```
> >         place_id                    lat         lng
> >     0   ChIJ3-pjozg3GEcRimBdVlmWd3k 51.112278   20.747889
> >     1   ChIJiR-APhQ3GEcR-57__9ZfvU0 51.131246   20.763574
> >     2   ChIJNyAvWs05GEcRVljgfRAvPGY 51.106695   20.793692
> >     3   ChIJPQWT5Lo5GEcR_czWyMwzGMg 51.112206   20.830048
> >     4   ChIJI2kwRsE5GEcRUJfB6O2QWa0 51.102545   20.785231
> >     5   ChIJNyxWu7k5GEcRUhZfdmNctD8 51.113777   20.823140
> >     6   ChIJjeNBPls3GEcR_hfosXw5KAQ 51.100790   20.751682
> >     7   ChIJp2Mxm2E5GEcReEsSfRqfunM 51.098479   20.836110
> >     8   ChIJ3aRDzrE5GEcR-hMBvF46sIQ 51.116702   20.835246
> ```

Comment: @Jaroslaw welcome, mate